# cart shows empty issue

Tags: magento-1.9, cart

I have a problem on my site which is after the customer adds all product he wants to the cart, and then when he clicks to the cart it shows him an empty cart.
this is not always happening but sometimes

I searched for it but I didn't find any like my issue.
also, I put the Session Lifetime to 86400 but didn't help

may Magento is 1.9

I hope I can find a solution for it.

thank you.

Comment: Please post the list of third party modules you are using in your website

Comment: It could be a cookie domain settings issue, especially if you have Varnish on your server. Can you check your cookie domain setting ?